# Predicate Logic Representation

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

How do you represent arithmetic operations with predicate logic?
For example if I want to represent 2+3 = 5 in predicate logic with plus(x,y) function is the following correct?

plus(2,3) <=> 5

But ideally <=> is equivalent and not equal. So is the above representation wrong?How do you represent something like this with predicate logic?

Comment: [First order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) with equality.

Comment: To clarify: Yes, wriging $plus(2,3) \leftrightarrow 5$ is wrong: $\leftrightarrow$ connects formulas (= expressions that come out as true or false), but $plus(2,3)$ and $5$ are not formulas, but terms (= expressions that stand for objects, such as numbers). The solution is to use $=$ as explained in mario's answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `plus` as a function symbol, then you may write `plus(2,3)=5`; if you wish to formalize as a predicate you need a ternary predicate `plus(2,3,5)`. The latter option is less common, but very fine too.

EDIT, July 2020

Just to be clear, if you use functions (and basic `=` rules), it is hard coded in the settings itself that, for all `a`, `b`, there is a unique `c` such that `plus(a,b)=c` (you may prove it!). In the predicate case, you need to state  that explicitly (add it as an axiom):

$\forall a,b \exists! c \; plus(a,b,c)$,

where $\exists!c$ is: `there is a unique c`, i.e.

$\forall a,b ( \exists c \; plus (a,b,c) \wedge ( \forall d,d' ( plus(a,b,d) \wedge plus(a,b,d') \rightarrow d=d' \; )))$,